# pthreads and opencl

Tags: pthreads, opencl

Can I create pthreads and inside each pthread can I create opencl environment and call the same kernel. What I am trying to do is launch opencl kernels in parallel on the same device. Is this possible?

Thanks for answering.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

At first sight this seams unnecessary.

When you launch an OpenCL kernel, using clEnqueueNDRange() API call, you can launch as many kernels  as you need; each as its own  thread on the same device.   The  OpenCL Model is that one  Context/Command Queue can launch 100 - 1000s  of light weight kernel threads on a GPU.

Answer (score 1):

Ya as Tim pointed out, when OpenCL supports so many threads/kernels why would you want to go inside pthreads with opencl. Further threads on the GPU are very light weight as compared to pthreads. Pthreads are costly and involved lot of overhead for context switching which might actually bring down your performance significantly.

But launching many kernels with the same command queue will execute the kernels sequentially. There should be different command queues for each kernel. I believe single context should not be a problem to launch the kernels parallely...

Comment: Is launching multiple kernels in parallel supported in 6970? Is there a opencl version that I need to use, the reason I am asking is I have created two command queues and I donot see speedup, well I am not expecting a linear speedup but then again.... I am using opencl version 1.1.

Comment: Well I don't see any reason why multiple kernels should not be supported in 6970. Its a bit difficult to answer this question but I  would have tried (silly though) varying input data size and check out the performance..

Comment: Thanks will try bigger matrices I have tried matrix transpose of size 1024*1024.

Comment: Here is a list of conforming OpenCL products  http://www.khronos.org/conformance/adopters/conformant-products/  AMD 6970 is supported

Comment: Are you using clEnqueueNDRangeKernel API call to launch your kernels?  What are you  Global and Local work group sizes and dimension ?

Comment: I have not used local work group sizes but my global work size is 512 I have used clEnqueueNDRangeKernel API call to launch my kernels.

Comment: Time taken as reported by app profiler single transpose 5 sec and performing two transposes 10 sec

Comment: Can anyone attach any example of concurrent kernels please? Thanks